# Get value of items in shopping cart and remove stock accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a **stock** type of system where when a user **clicks** a button it checks which Items are in the shopping cart and what their names are and the subtotal price of the single product.

So if the subtotal is *1$* I know that the quantity of that product is *1* and then subtract that from the stock in the MySQL database, and if the subtotal is *2$* I know that the quantity is *2* and subtract *2* of the stock of that specific product.

What I've done so far is get the first `h4` text and check if that is equal to a product name and then check the price to get the quantity and all of that would be in a if else statement which is a pretty bad way of doing it since I would have to make about *360* if else checks.

This is an example of how a shopping cart could look like and there can be more products in the shopping cart or the price could be more since the quantity per product can be higher

```
<div class="list-group sc-cart-item-list">
    <div class="sc-cart-item list-group-item" data-unique-key="1586696968143">
        <button type="button" class="sc-cart-remove">×</button>
        <img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Iphone 11 6.1</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Yellow</p>
        <div class="sc-cart-item-summary">
            <span class="sc-cart-item-price">19,99&nbsp;€</span> × <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" class="sc-cart-item-qty" value="1"> = <span class="sc-cart-item-amount">19,99&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sc-cart-item list-group-item" data-unique-key="1586697501762">
    <button type="button" class="sc-cart-remove">×</button>
    <img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Iphone XS Max</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Orange</p>
    <div class="sc-cart-item-summary">
        <span class="sc-cart-item-price">19,99&nbsp;€</span> × <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" class="sc-cart-item-qty" value="1"> = <span class="sc-cart-item-amount">19,99&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the script I have so far but its generally very bad since first of all the part where I check the price in a if statement doesn't work and I would have to do this 360 times over for every possible quantiy someone can buy and every possible variation of the product

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vbutton").click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        var w = $('h4', '').first().text();
        //console.log(v);

        var a = $('.sc-cart-item-amount', '').first().text();
        //console.log(a);



        if (w !== '') {

            console.log("Hi");

            if (w == "Iphone 11 6.1") {

                console.log(a);
                if (a == '19,99 €') {
                    console.log("removed 1 from database");
                }

            }


        }

    });
});

</script>
```

Then I would need to do this for the second, third, fourth and so on text that could be in the shopping Cart.
I would really appreciate any help possible, thank you.

Comment: So you basically want the selected product name along with its amount without having to run soo many if statements yeah ?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to say you want to parse the ''19,99 €'' ?

```js
parseInt('19,99 €'.replace(/,/g, ''));
// 1999
```

Then you can do some calculate, and get the quantity.